# Running my Python script returns "NoneType"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code returns NoneType when I add `.text` it returns `NoneType` and when I delete `.text` it return `None` in `dataframe`. How can I resolve this issue?

```
data_adi = []
n=0
for n in range(pagenum):
    pages_url = f"https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/search?page={n+1}&criteria=Tp- link%20Usa%20Corporation"
    driver.get(pages_url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*   [@id="nwrap"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[2]/ul')))
    time.sleep(5)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = Soup(html)

    for item in soup.select("div", class_='[class="flex-container"]'):
    
        data_adi.append({
           'title' : item.find("div", class_="rd-item-name").text,
           'name' : item.find("span", class_='item-num-mfg').text,
           'link' : item.find("div", class_="rd-item-name", href=True)['href'],
           'price' : item.find("div", class_="pdp-price-wrapper").text,
           'stock' : item.find("span", class_="availabilityMessage-rd").text
       })
    
df_adi = pd.DataFrame(data_adi)
df_adi.drop_duplicates()
df_adi
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You first need to make sure, element is not Null.

```
 node = child.find('title')
 if node is not None:
        = node.text
 else:
        = None
```

Or use build in Function getattr:

```
    ... = getattr(child.find('title'), 'text', None)
```